# Why do I fail to load the dylib?

Tags: macos, compilation, clang

Here is the command I typed:

```
clang++ -Iboost -Ijpeg_lib/include/ -Ljpeg_lib/lib/ -ljpeg.9 mandelbrot.cpp
```

The directory structure is like this:

```
mandelbrot.cpp
/boost
/jpeg_lib/lib/
    libjpeg.9.dylib
/jpeg_lib/include/
```

The compilation is successful, but when I run the binary file, an error occurs:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Users/hanxu/Documents/./a.out
>
> Reason: image not found
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5

I have specified the library searching path to jpeg_lib/include/, why does the program still search at /usr/local/lib ?

Comment: That dot in "`/Users/hanxu/Documents/./a.out`" looks really strange to me.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I just copied the command line result. I use "./a.out" to run my program. It is strange to me too..

Comment: is the command line tool you're building an Xcode project or is this via a Makefile?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, Makefile, I was downloaded from here: http://www.ijg.org

Comment: is "`libjpeg.9.dylib`" in "`/jpeg_lib/lib`" a real file or is it a (broken) symbolic link to "`/usr/local/lib`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I believe it is a real file. It is generated through "make install" from IJG.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, there are two file in the "/jpeg_lib/lib", one is "libjpeg.9.dylib", which is a real file. The other one is "libjpeg.dylib", which is a symbolic link I think, because there is a little arrow in the left-lower corner.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I have figured out. I specified the path for compilation. But after compiling, the program will search the dynamical library file in the path specified by the system. So I have to copy the .dylib file to /usr/local/lib...

Answer (score 1):

You should include the directory where `libjpeg.9.dylib` lives in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is required to locate the libraries at runtime:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libjpeg`

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is Linux (UNIX), under OSX it's `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked permissions on your jpeg_lib ? If you installed whatever it is you are running as root and then ran as yourself this may have happened.

I just had the same error message with running GD graphics from a Perl cgi after a portmanteau install as root and found that the /usr/local/lib directory in which my libjpeg.9.dylib resides had permissions 700. Changing to 755 (like all the other directories in /usr/local) solved the problem.